# Show that this function is differentiable at a given point and indicate the linear and little-o terms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

I have the function: $f(x,y) = x^2-xy+3y^2$

I want to show that this function is differentiable at $(1,1)$ using the definition of differentiability. I'm asked to also indicate the linear and little-o terms and prove that the little-o terms are, in fact, little-o terms.

To start I set $x=1+h_1$ and $y=1+h_2$ so I now have $f(1+h_1,1+h_2) = (1+h_1)^2 - (1+h_1)(1+h_2) + 3(1+h_2)^2$

I then expanded and simplified to get $3+h_1+5h_2+{h_1}^2-h_1h_2+{h_2}^2$

But from here I'm not sure where to go and how I can simplify further or show which terms are linear or little-o.

Any help or hints for the next step/steps I would take to find the answer would be really helpful. (Just to bear in mind for the explanations, I have very little experience with little-o so I'm not very familiar with it and its concepts)

Comment: Calculate partial derivatives and consider difference between function and its linear approximation - it should be little-$o$.

Comment: The little o-terms are $h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2$. This doesn't help much as you need to consider all four cases, where $h_1 < 0, h_1 > 0$ and $h_2 < 0, h_2 > 0$ so you can't come up with a bounding argument.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f'_x(1,1)=2x-y\Big|_{(1,1)}=1$ and $f'_y(1,1)=-x+6y\Big|_{(1,1)}=5$.

Now we need to show that difference between change in function and its linear approxiamtion $\overbrace{f(1+h_1,1+h_2)-f(1,1)}^{\text{change in function}}-\overbrace{f'_x(1,1)h_1-f'_y(1,1)h_2}^{\text{linear approximation}}$  is little-$o$ with respect to $\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}$, which comes from
$$\frac{\overbrace{\overbrace{(1+h_1)^2-(1+h_1)(1+h_2)+3(1+h_2)^2}^{f(1+h_1,1+h_2)}-\overbrace{3}^{f(1,1)}}^{\text{change in function}}-\overbrace{\overbrace{h_1}^{f'_x(1,1)h_1}-\overbrace{5h_2}^{f'_y(1,1)h_2}}^{\text{linear approximation}}}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}=\\=\frac{\overbrace{h_1^2+3h_2^2+h_1h_2}^{\text{little -o}}}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\to 0$$
when $(h_1,h_2)\to (0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function as

$$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}.$$

If we call the matrix $A$ and $\vec x:=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$, this can be very compactly written as $f(\vec x)=\vec x^TA\vec x$. Now to examine it at $\vec x_0=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$:

$$\begin{align}f(\vec x_0+\vec h)&=(\vec x_0+\vec h)^TA(\vec x_0+\vec h)\\
&=\vec x_0^TA\vec x_0+\vec h^TA\vec x_0+\vec x_0^TA\vec h+\vec h^TA\vec h\\
&=\vec x_0^TA\vec x_0+\vec x_0^T(A^T+A)\vec h + \vec h^TA\vec h\end{align}$$

In this form, it should be relatively clear which terms are constant, linear, or little-o: the first summand is clearly constant, the second is a matrix multiplied to $\vec h$, so clearly linear, and the last one contains two instances of $\vec h$, so should intuitively identified as "quadratic" in $\vec h$, so that's the little-o term (which you should still verify).